# Can't find function unauthenticated() function in laravel 5.6.12 for admin and customer login redirect?

Tags: php, laravel

How can admin and user be redirected in laravel  5.6.12? I cannot find unauthenticated function in app/Exceptions/Handler.php file..

Comment: You need to setup a middleware to check upon login of what the user is (admin or user)

Answer (score 2):

The `unauthenticated` method exists in the parent handler, `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`. Just override it, like so;

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401);
    }

    $guard = $exception->guards()[0];

    return redirect(route($guard . ':auth.create'));
}
```